# serviceworker mobile offline

Tags: offline, service-worker

I forked the 2048 game to work offline using the CSS tricks service worker offline tutorial.

For some reason I can't get it to work on my mobile in aeroplane mode but it does work on the browser in offline mode.

Any ideas? 
https://www.dhrubopaul.co.uk/2048-demo-offline/

https://www.dhrubopaul.co.uk/2048-demo-offline/service-worker.js

Comment: What mobile OS are you using? What browser? Which version of the browser?

Comment: Nexus 5x android v6 with the latest chrome

Comment: Managed to get it to work using the service worker cache polyfiller by the chrome team.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's currently missing some useful cache methods, importScripts('serviceworker-cache-polyfill.js') managed to fix all the issues.